# Implicitly default-constructible meaning?

Tags: c++, c++11

On [this reference page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple) for `std::tuple` it is said that the default constructor for the type is "explicit if and only if `Ti` is not implicitly default-constructible for at least one `i`".

I'm a bit confused what it means by "implicitly default-constructible". Can someone give me an example?

Answer (score 11):

Here's an example:

```
struct A {};
struct B { explicit B() = default; };

int main()
{
    A a1 = {};
    A a2 {};

    // B b1 = {}; // Error, would use explicit default constructor
    B b2 {};
}
```

Constructors with `explicit` have become a lot more relevant since C++11 thanks to list-initialization.

Comment: I see. Is there a type trait we can use to test if a type is implicitly default-constructible?

Comment: @ZizhengTai, I don't think so. You could make one given that `T t = {};` doesn't require a copy or move constructor in C++17.

Comment: @chris So there isn't a way to do this pre-C++17?

Comment: @ZizhengTai, You could detect that if this works and copy-construction also works, but if copy-construction doesn't work, then you wouldn't know. I can't think of any clever tests off the top of my head, but that doesn't mean it can't be done.

Comment: @ZizhengTai: The Standard gives a hint: "This behavior can be implemented with a trait that checks whether a `const T&` can be initialized with `{}`."

Comment: @KerrekSB Trying this has only led me to all sorts of compiler bugs :D

Comment: @KerrekSB, Heh good point. I didn't think of a const reference.

Answer (score 8):

This means, for `std::tuple<T1,T2,...,Tn>` to be implicitly default-constructed, all of `Ti`  types must.

#### Example of implicitly default-constructible tuple

For instance, since `std::string` and `std::vector`  are implicitly default-constructible (their default constructor are not `explicit`), `std::tuple<std::string, std::vector>` is:

```
void f(std::tuple<std::string, std::vector<int>>);

f({}); // valid and equivalent to:
std::string sempty;
std::vector<int> vempty;
auto tsv = std::make_tuple(sempty, vempty);
f(tsv);
```

#### Example of not implicitly default-constructible tuple

With a non-implicit default-constructible type `A`, `std::tuple<std::string, A>` can't be implicitly default-constructed:

```
struct A
{
    explicit A() = default;
};

void f(std::tuple<std::string, A>);

f({}); // error
```